# ruby and selenium-webdriver -> Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)

Tags: software-installation, ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium

I want to run a ruby script on my Raspberry Pi. I've installed ruby via rvm. I'm sure, i'm using the right version:

```
$ rvm current
ruby-1.9.3-p194
```

when i run my script, then i get following:

```
./test.rb 
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:25:in `initialize': Address family not supported by protocol - socket(2) (Errno::EAFNOSUPPORT)
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:25:in `new'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:25:in `block in free?'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:23:in `each'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:23:in `free?'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:5:in `above'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.rb:33:in `default_service'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:14:in `initialize'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
from /home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
from ./test.rb:82:in `block in <main>'
from ./test.rb:54:in `each'
from ./test.rb:54:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas, what is wrong? I've tried to restart, this doesn't solve the problem...

**edit**: here the content of test.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get "http://www.google.com" 

headless.destroy
```

Comment: Your ruby install is current.

Comment: Please post test.rb.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3603373/961353

Comment: Could you try running you script through strace, like `strace -f -e socket -O /tmp/trace.txt ./test.rb` and paste /tmp/trace.txt content?

Comment: this script works on ubuntu...but not here, so i'm pretty sure, that my code is correct. Here one line output from strace: [pid 14694] socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = -1 EAFNOSUPPORT (Address family not supported by protocol). Maybe i must disable ipv6 and only use ipv4...

Comment: Yeah, try that. Also, look at ifconfig and see if you have an IPv6 address. You can also try running `ping6 ipv6.google.com`

Comment: Did you find how to fix Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError problem ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...i've disabled ipv6. For that, i made changes in the files `/etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf` and `/etc/hosts`. They looks as follow:

**/etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf**

```
# Don't load ipv6 by default
alias net-pf-10 off
alias ipv6 off
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1            localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0                ip6-localnet
#ff00::0                ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1                ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2                ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

Now i get another exception, but this is a problem with my chromedriver (`unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError`) and not with the exception above. This is easy to solve imho. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your answer helped get rmate working on my pi... so I think Selenium was a victim, and the problem lies in the ip stack.